# change order of list in tableview by clicking on whole cell

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, tableview, uitableview

I currently have a 'tableview' with a list of items and I have enabled an 'edit' button to go into edit mode which shows the 'reordering controls' on the right side of the screen. I have also enabled 'canMoveRowAtIndexPath' and 'moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath' to allow for the user to hold and drag the reorder control on the right side to reorder the list and have the data model update.

Is there a way to enable this but allow the user to click and drag the whole cell and not only the 'reorder controller'? Essentially I want to enlarge the area of the reorder controller's function to the whole cell when tableview is in editing mode.

Comment: for anyone else who is interested, I used this guide to get it working: [b2cloud](http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/reordering-a-uitableviewcell-from-any-touch-point)

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else who is interested, I used this guide to get it working: [b2cloud](http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/reordering-a-uitableviewcell-from-any-touch-point)
the starting code template does not work as optimally since it has nib files and I'm using Xcode5 but it still works. The important code is all in the actualy tutorial as he lists how to set the reorder control to the size of the size via inserting it as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to enable this that allow the user to click and drag the whole cell and not only the 'reorder controller'!

Please check it out: https://github.com/FlorianMielke/FMMoveTableView

This might be helpful to you, Sir :)